# How to get the hierarchy of Vehicle API by year, model, make using MMPickerView for an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uipickerview

I used ccpickerview but now decided to changed to MMPickerView.But I am failing to pass json data of the vehicle make and model based on the year selected. I can get the year from jsonData. when I click picker for Make of the vehicles the app crashes with this error;

Loaded

```
2015-02-10 21:51:22.105 VehicleApp[2099:872363] PostData: year=2013&tag=vehMake
2015-02-10 21:51:22.728 VehicleApp[2099:872363] Response code: 200
2015-02-10 21:51:22.731 Vehicle[2099:872363] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[6]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

The web service is fine because when I used CCPickerView the condition was   pretty straight forward following this hierarchy > pick "year" > then "make" of vehicles in the year are parse from JSON > pick "make" > then "model" of the vehicle pulled from json. that’s all I want

In my previous CCPickerView class I had this condition;

```
    - (void)pickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item
{
    if (self.yearsPicker == pickerView) {

        [self setVahicleModel:[self.years objectAtIndex:item]];
        Yyear =[self.years objectAtIndex:item];
    }

    if (self.modelPicker == pickerView) {
        Mmake =[self.model objectAtIndex:item];
        [self setVahicle:Mmake Varient:Yyear];

    }

    if (self.varientPicker == pickerView) {
        Mmodel =[self.varient objectAtIndex:item];
    }

    if (self.insurerPicker == pickerView) {
        Iinsurer =[self.insurer objectAtIndex:item];

    }

    if (self.financePicker == pickerView) {
        Ffinance =[self.finance objectAtIndex:item];

    }

}
```

How can I get the same results using MMPickerView?
Here is my ViewDidLoad

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setVehicleYear];
    // [self setVehicleMake];
    // [self setVehicleModel];

    _selectedYear = [years objectAtIndex:0];
    _selectedMake = [make objectAtIndex:0];
    _selectedModel = [model objectAtIndex:0];


}
```

Any idea or suggestion what I am doing wrong in this code below;

```
    - (IBAction)selectYear:(id)sender {
    //PickerView using array of objects, with selectedObject functionality
    [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                           withObjects:years
                           withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                         MMvalueY: @3,
                                         MMselectedObject:_selectedYear
                                         }
               objectToStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
                   return [object description];
               }
                            completion:^(id selectedObject) {
                                _lblYear.text = [selectedObject description];
                                _selectedYear = selectedObject;
                            }];


}

    - (IBAction)selectMake:(id)sender {

    [self setVehicleMake];

    //PickerView using array of objects, with selectedObject functionality
    [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                           withObjects:make
                           withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                         MMvalueY: @3,
                                         MMselectedObject:_selectedMake
                                         }
               objectToStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
                   return [object description];
               }
                            completion:^(id selectedObject) {
                                _lblMake.text = [selectedObject description];
                                _selectedMake = selectedObject;
                            }];
}


    - (IBAction)selectModel:(id)sender {
    [self setVehicleModel];
    //PickerView using array of objects, with selectedObject functionality
    [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                           withObjects:model
                           withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                         MMvalueY: @3,
                                         MMselectedObject:_selectedModel
                                         }
               objectToStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
                   return [object description];
               }
                            completion:^(id selectedObject) {
                                _lblModel.text = [selectedObject description];
                                _selectedModel = selectedObject;
                            }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did, with MMPicketView  and works fine, hope this solutions helps others.

```objective-c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self setVehicleYear];

     selectedYear = [years objectAtIndex:0];
    _selectedInsurer = [insurer objectAtIndex:0];
    _selectedFinance = [finance objectAtIndex:0];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)selectYear:(id)sender {

    //PickerView using array of objects, with selectedObject functionality
    [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                           withObjects:years
                           withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                         MMvalueY: @3,
                                         MMselectedObject:selectedYear
                                         }
               objectToStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
                   return [object description];
               }
                            completion:^(id selectedObject) {
                                _lblYear.text = [selectedObject description];
                                selectedYear = selectedObject;
                                [self setVehicleMake:selectedYear];
                                selectedMake = [make objectAtIndex:0];
                             }];
}
- (IBAction)selectMake:(id)sender {
    //PickerView using array of objects, with selectedObject functionality
    [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                           withObjects:make
                           withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                         MMvalueY: @3,
                                         MMselectedObject:selectedMake
                                         }
               objectToStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
                   return [object description];
               }
                            completion:^(id selectedObject) {
                                _lblMake.text = [selectedObject description];
                                selectedMake = selectedObject;
                                [self setVehicleModel:selectedMake Varient:selectedYear];
                                selectedModel = [varient objectAtIndex:0];
                             }];
}
- (IBAction)selectModel:(id)sender {
    //PickerView using array of objects, with selectedObject functionality
    [MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                           withObjects:varient
                           withOptions:@{MMbackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMtextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMtoolbarColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                         MMbuttonColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                         MMfont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18],
                                         MMvalueY: @3,
                                         MMselectedObject:selectedModel
                                         }
               objectToStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
                   return [object description];
               }
                            completion:^(id selectedObject) {
                                _lblModel.text = [selectedObject description];
                                selectedModel = selectedObject;
                            }];

}
```

Comment: You can accept your answer by clicking on the green tick. This marks the problem as solved in Stack Overflow.